# I've noticed some jobs have an Express Interest button. Some don't. Why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Why do some jobs *not* have an "express interest" button?

Comment: I thought that was what the unicorn button was for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From what I can see, those that do not have the "express interest" buttons are jobs that are not actually posted on Stack Overflow Jobs but on an external site and then syndicated here.

See how the "Apply Now" button has an icon to show that the application process would take you off-site:

> [image]

As opposed to those that were posted directly to Jobs, and thus are fully integrated with the site's features:

> [image]

Comment: That's correct. "Express Interest" is only supported for jobs which use the internal apply flow.

Comment: Could probably be made clearer. Grey out the button with an explanatory tooltip? But [we've been over this before](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/120848/18837)

Comment: Also the text alignment on those buttons is all over the place (a common theme at the moment; I've raised two bugs about this in other places on the site just this week so far!)

Comment: Cool. I didn't notice that.